# JS: Returning the return

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have a function `Main` in which there is function `kid` in javascript. 
I want to run to run `return` of `Main` from the `kid` function. How do I do it

In `kid` function, I wrote a command `return return;` which gave the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

I know the long process like return a true value from `kid` function and then checking value in Main and then `return` but I want to know whether there is a better method

**Edit:**

```
    function Main() {
      if (a=2) {
       //some code X here
       kid();
       } else if (a=3) {
       //some code Y here
       } else if (a=4) {
       //some code Z here
       kid();
       }

       //some code here
       return;

    }

function kid() {
//some checks here 
//if the check fails I want to return from the function Main()
}
```

Comment: `return` is token so you cant use it as variable

Comment: Good to know you have these functions . Are you also going to show us? Or we have to guess about them? :)

Comment: It looks like what you really want is to pass a function, but your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: You mean something like this `function Main() { function kid() { return true}; return kid(); }` ? Or are you trying to assign the value returned by `kid()` to a `return` variable?

Comment: I have added the code here

Comment: You might want to throw an exception in kid().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have probably comes from your `return return;` you can't use return as a variable since it's a javascript reserved word like `if`, `for`, etc.

Concerning your issue : you will not be able to end the main function directly in your kid function. (that might be possible but really dirty plus you will end up with lots of code)

IMO a simple thing you can do is : Do your checks in the `kid()` function and `return true` if checks pass or `false` if they don't. Then, call kid in your main function and `return;` if kid returns false.
something like :

```
function Main() {
   if (a=2) {
      //some code X here
      if(!kid()) {return;}
   } else if (a=3) {
      //some code Y here
   } else if (a=4) {
      //some code Z here
      if(!kid() {return;}
   }

   //some code here
   return;

 }

function kid() {
   if (/*some checks here*/) {
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```